# How to implement a Meteor Tracker enabled feature?

Tags: javascript, meteor, jestjs, meteor-tracker

I am writing a module supporting Meteor Tracker, but I am unable to test it. I added [`meteor-standalone-tracker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-standalone-tracker) as dev dependency, and wrote a test case, but the `autorun` function is called only once.

For example, I wrote a dummy test inspired [from the docs](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/tracker-manual.md) as follow

```
import assert from 'assert';
import Tracker from 'trackr';

describe('Testing Tracker', () => {

  it('should do as expected', () => {

    var favoriteFood = "apples";
    var favoriteFoodDep = new Tracker.Dependency;

    var getFavoriteFood = function () {
      favoriteFoodDep.depend();
      return favoriteFood;
    };

    var setFavoriteFood = function (newValue) {
      favoriteFood = newValue;
      favoriteFoodDep.changed();
    };

    console.log("GET:" , getFavoriteFood());
    // "apples"

    var handle = Tracker.autorun(function () {
      console.log("Your favorite food is " + getFavoriteFood());
    });
    // "Your favorite food is apples"

    setFavoriteFood("mangoes");
    // "Your favorite food is mangoes"
    setFavoriteFood("peaches");
    // "Your favorite food is peaches"
    setFavoriteFood("bananas");
    // "Your favorite food is bananas"
    handle.stop();
    setFavoriteFood("cake");
    // (nothing printed)

  });

});
```

The the *only* output I get is this :

```
console.log test/tracker.spec.js:27
   GET: apples

console.log test/tracker.spec.js:31
   Your favorite food is apples
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to flush all calculations.

```
Tracker.flush();
```

This will force the `autorun` functions with dependencies that have changed to be called.